# PHP GD fails silently

Tags: php, png, gd, freebsd

I've been working on an image processing function that loads PNG files. While it works fine on my local server (Windows, PHP 5.3.6) on the remote server (FreeBSD, PHP 5.3.6) PHP returns a "500 Internal Server Error" when using imagecreatefrompng. Normally, I'd consult the logs in /var/log/php.log - but nothing is added to the log when I try and load the page. If I comment out the line containing imagecreatefrompng the script loads - albeit with many errors output into the log because of the missing image resource.

I've tried adding:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to the code, no difference.

The output of phpinfo shows that GD is loaded, the output of gd_info is:

```
array(12) {
  ["GD Version"]=>
  string(27) "bundled (2.0.34 compatible)"
  ["FreeType Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["FreeType Linkage"]=>
  string(13) "with freetype"
  ["T1Lib Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["GIF Read Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["GIF Create Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["JPEG Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["PNG Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["WBMP Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["XPM Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["XBM Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

At this point, I'm completely lost. Short of nuking my php install and trying over again, I don't know what to do. I plan to upgrade to 5.4 once the port is updated, but considering I can't tell what the issue is - I don't know if that will fix things.

Here's a snippet of the code in question:

```
/* load image */
$imgname = '/images/'.$doctype.'_'.side($_GET['side']).".png";
$image_path = trim(shell_exec('pwd')).$imgname;

if(!file_exists($image_path)){
  trigger_error('Image file not found!');
  exit;
}
$im = imagecreatefrompng($image_path);
```

I've gone as far as making sure I'm using the absolute path to the image, double checking the image exists (file_exists()) and errorring out if it doesn't. Regardless of what I do, as long as imagecreatefrompng is uncommented, I get a silent 500 error.

Edit: I've added the snippet:

```
var_dump(is_readable($image_path));
var_dump(file_exists($image_path));
```

to my code which results in:

```
bool(true) bool(true)
```

So it looks like the image file is readable by PHP. I've also verified the image is an actual PNG file. Any other ideas?

Comment: Without logs, how are you sure that this specific line is where the 500 happens?  Have you put a `die()` immediately after `imagecreatefrompng()` to see if you still get the HTTP error?

Comment: Are you sure you are tailing the correct php log file? `php -i | fgrep -i error` from the command line to make sure. Also make sure `log_errors` is turned on.

Comment: Farry: as I mentioned in the post, if I comment out that line it works. If I uncomment the imagecreatefrompng function; 500 error.

Comment: Mike: Yes. I've tailed the log and used trigger_error to confirm the output. All other errors show up in that file. Log errors is enabled.

Comment: I am having a similar issue: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1969 with GD installed in Docker PHP-FPM. Enabled and all that, but when I try to use it instead of Imagemagick (also installed) it results in an error 500 uploading an image with Dropzone and manipulation with Intervention whereas with the same image and Imagick all is fine. Did you ever solve this issue @kagaku ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the file permissions?

```
if(!file_exists($path) || !is_readable($path))....
```

sometimes it got me.

and, I don't it's that but... are you check before that if it's really a png file??

Comment: I tried adding: var_dump(is_readable($image_path)); var_dump(file_exists($image_path)); - this output: bool(true) bool(true); I verified the image is a png file as well.